# JMeter: How to capture dynamic request parameter values in HTTP Request

Tags: dynamic, jmeter

I have recorded a login script which has form_key parameter as dynamic. With the user of regular expression extractor, how can I capture the dynamic value in form_key?

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract this `form_key` parameter from **previous** response, i.e.

- GET request to login page

  - [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to fetch `form_key` (usually [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter))
- POST request to login page (credentials and `form_key` from the previous response)

Also I would suggest to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.

If you experience any problems - feel free to use [JMeter Magento Login Test Plan](http://pastebin.com/t00RaVvH) for reference